# Can GHCI be used to explain coercions?

Tags: haskell

How to ask GHCI to explain why the following:

```
*Lib> sum Nothing
0
```

Even compiles? Was there `Monoid` involved somehow? It's not in the signature!

```
*Lib> :i Foldable
class Foldable (t :: * -> *) where
  ...
  maximum :: Ord a => t a -> a
  minimum :: Ord a => t a -> a
  sum :: Num a => t a -> a
  product :: Num a => t a -> a
        -- Defined in ‘Data.Foldable’
instance Foldable [] -- Defined in ‘Data.Foldable’
instance Foldable Maybe -- Defined in ‘Data.Foldable’
instance Foldable (Either a) -- Defined in ‘Data.Foldable’
instance Foldable ((,) a) -- Defined in ‘Data.Foldable’
*Lib> :i Num
class Num a where
  (+) :: a -> a -> a
  (-) :: a -> a -> a
  (*) :: a -> a -> a
  negate :: a -> a
  abs :: a -> a
  signum :: a -> a
  fromInteger :: Integer -> a
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
instance Num Word -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
instance Num Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
instance Num Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
instance Num Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
*Lib> sum Nothing
0
```

Comment: I can't answer your question about introspection, but I can point out that [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#line-218) is the reason behind your underlying question :)

Comment: (and in fact the `:i` output you provided says "Instance Foldable Maybe -- Defined in `Data.Foldable`". That plus inspecting `Nothing` to see that it's a `Maybe` (if you didn't already know that) does the job?)

Comment: Why don't you just see the type of `sum` using `:t sum`. It will indicate that it has to have `Foldable` instance and all you have figure out is that `Maybe` instance for `Foldable`.

Comment: You answered your own question. The output of `:i` says: `sum :: Num a => t a -> a` and `instance Foldable Maybe`. From this it follows that `sum Nothing` is well-typed since `Nothing :: Maybe a` for every `a`, and so it has also type `Nothing :: Num a => Maybe a`, which can be passed to `sum`.  The result of `0` obviously comes from how `sum` is defined for empty `Foldable`s.

Comment: I would think that `0` comes from `Monoid Sum` in ` sum = getSum #. foldMap Sum` definition.

Comment: @sevo And you would be right.

Answer (score 6):

You can use typed holes:

```
> sum (Nothing :: _)
<interactive>:4:17:
    Found hole `_' with type: Maybe a
    Where: `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
               the inferred type of it :: Num a => a at <interactive>:4:1
    To use the inferred type, enable PartialTypeSignatures
    Relevant bindings include it :: a (bound at <interactive>:4:1)
    In an expression type signature: _
    In the first argument of `sum', namely `(Nothing :: _)'
    In the expression: sum (Nothing :: _)
```

Which says that `a` is a rigid type variable bound by the inferred type of `it :: Num a => a`, and since `Maybe` is an instance of `Foldable` (as you have already posted in the output to `:i Foldable`, although you can also see in the output to `:i Maybe`) it compiles presuming that `Nothing :: Num a => Maybe a`, since `sum` places that `Num` constraint on it.

So the reason why it compiles is that `sum` accepts a `Foldable` containing `Num a => a` values, and `Maybe` is a `Foldable`, `Nothing` by itself has type `Maybe a`, and `sum` places the constraint that `a` must implement `Num`.  When in GHCi, this defaults to `Integer`, so you see the output of `0`.